# Issue adding a reaction to an embed message in Discord. (Discord.py 2.2.2)

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to solve this problem for the last 3 hours now.

```
check_emoji = "\u2705"
    msg = await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction(check_emoji)
```

Here is the context of the command:

```
@tree.command(name="lfg", description="Looking for Group", guild=discord.Object(id=1016733173482274826))
async def self(interaction: discord.Interaction, game_mode:str, number_of_players:int, description:str, vc_or_text:str):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Looking for Group", description=description, color=0x00ff00)
    embed.add_field(name="Game Mode", value=game_mode, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Number of Players", value=number_of_players, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="VC or Text", value=vc_or_text, inline=True)
    check_emoji = "\u2705"
    msg = await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction(check_emoji)
    open_posts = []
    open_posts.append(msg)
    while len(open_posts) > 0:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=lambda reaction, user: str(reaction.emoji) == check_emoji and not user.bot)
        if msg in open_posts:
            if number_of_players > 1:
                number_of_players -= 1
                embed.set_field_at(1, name="Number of Players", value=number_of_players, inline=True)
                await msg.edit(embed=embed)
            else:
                embed.set_title("Looking for Group (Closed)")
                embed.set_color(0xff0000)
                await msg.edit(embed=embed)
                open_posts.remove(msg)
                await msg.clear_reactions()
    await interaction.response.send_message("Post has been removed from the list of posts.")
```

This is the output I keep getting. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'lfg' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'
```

I've revised the code several times whilst referencing the libraries in Discord.py but I don't understand the context very well.

Other stack overflow posts regarding this don't seem to be updated or aren't using the same context that I am.

Thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Where the code says `msg = await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)`, what do you expect to end up as the value of `msg`, and **why**? What does the documentation for the `send_message` method tell you? Aside from that, please remember that this is **not a discussion forum**; we do not deal in "appreciated thoughts", but in answers to *clear, direct, explicit, properly researched* questions. Please also read [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in the following line of code:

```
interaction.response.send_message
```

does not return a message object unlike `ctx.send`.
interaction.response.send_message will always return None, what you want to do instead is get the message object with the following line:

```
msg = await interaction.original_response()
```

Then you can use add_reaction function on the `msg` variable.
Full code:

```
check_emoji = "\u2705"
msg = await interaction.original_response()
await msg.add_reaction(check_emoji)
```

Cheers, Eric